java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class <package- name>viewmodel.LoginViewModel
i have encountered this issue.
i am using jetpack compose with android hilt in my current android project.
Application crashes as soon as the activity appears in the screen.
After viewing many solution, many suggested to make

@AndroidEntryPoint
or
val viewModel = hiltViewModel()

 @Composable
    fun NextPage() {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val viewModel = hiltViewModel<LoginViewModel>()

        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "signin") {
            composable("signin") { SignInScreen(navController,viewModel) }
     

but it keep crashing after implementing all those points
After viewing many solution, many suggested to make
@AndroidEntryPoint


`val viewModel = hiltViewModel<LoginViewModel>()`



@Composable
    fun NextPage() {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val viewModel = hiltViewModel<LoginViewModel>()

        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "signin") {
            composable("signin") { SignInScreen(navController,viewModel) }
     



added few dependencies in the build.gradle in app level

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.4
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.4
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.5
 


but it keep crashing, after implementing all those above mentioned points

is there a chance we would be able to pull the project off github? the code seems correct

I found solution from android google documentation I added one more dependencies in android gradle
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0")


 @Composable
    fun NextPage() {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val viewModel = hiltViewModel<LoginViewModel>()

        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "signin") {
            composable("signin") { SignInScreen(navController,viewModel) }
     

and then it worked
